# PyQt: Basic example of accessing and adding a submenu to an existing context menu?

Tags: python, plugins, pyqt, contextmenu, pyqt4

Note: I have very little python and PyQt experience...

Given a context menu already created, I'm looking for a functional example of how I would gain access to that context menu, so it can be extended for a plugin which is doing the python equivalent of a javascript greasemonkey script.  Then I'm also looking for a functional example of how I could add a submenu to that context menu.  Thanks!

Comment: Did you create the context menu, or are you trying to extend a default context menu of a specific widget?

Comment: What do you mean by 'access'? If you are *given* a context menu (`QMenu` to be specific) you can access it. And adding a submenu to it is sort of trivial if you look at the [docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qmenu.html#addMenu). It would be better if you posted what you tried, what you expect and what doesn't work.

Comment: jdi: I'm trying to extend the context menu of MusicBrainz Picard, from a plugin.  Re Karnisov's suggested answer below, I've tried using self, trying to replicate how the existing context menu code creates itself, but get errors that self is not defined.  I tried asking a similar version of this same question yesterday, but in much longer form w/code extracts ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184157/pyqt-add-a-submenu-to-a-context-menu-via-a-plugin ).

Comment: https://github.com/musicbrainz/picard/blob/master/picard/ui/itemviews.py#L213 is the context menu creation code (My code would exist separately, in a plugin file - see the stuff in that same file up around line 54.)

Comment: You can't do this without modifying *that* file. It assumes it has given a list of `QAction`s (see line 301) and it wouldn't be expecting `QMenu`. Though, if you can get to the `plugin_menu` reference in your plugin, that's a different story. Does it's plugin api expose that?

Comment: No, the plugin api currently doesn't expose it.  I'm starting to think there's no way to pull this off without patching the code to add just that.  With that, then it'd be easy, right?  Something like

    def get_plugin_menu():
        return plugin_menu

Then:
    thisSubMenu = get_plugin_menu().addMenu("Search")
...and so on?

Comment: Sure. Then you will add your actions to `thisSubMenu` and they will be shown under the submenu `search`. This will be fine for personal use, but if you're going to distribute your plugin you need to distribute the changed source also. Alternatively you might contact the developers and suggest a `submenu` feature. They might be interested in adding this. Better yet, you could do this and send them a patch :).

Comment: Yeah, if I have to patch to get it to work, that'd definitely be in the cards.  Avaris, your last 2 comments together are really the best answer, for my original question; did you want to add them as an answer so I can accept it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avaris' comments basically answered this question the best.  I can't select it, though, because it's comments, rather than an answer.  So I'm summarizing that answer here, so this Q can be answered:

"If you are given a context menu (QMenu to be specific) you can access it." - Avaris

"You can't do this without modifying that file [the one containing the context menu creation code]. It assumes it has given a list of QActions (see line 301) and it wouldn't be expecting QMenu. Though, if you can get to the plugin_menu reference in your plugin, that's a different story." - Avaris

So either you can access to manipulate the menu in the same file (and same place in that file) where the menu creation/definition code is, or you can gain access to do so via that file (in the same place) exposing the menu via an API.  On the flip side, if you don't have such API access, and/or modify that file/function, then there's no way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

The customContextMenuRequested signal would be connected to a method/function (called a slot in Qt), look for a line of code that resembles this to get an idea of what method/function you need to adjust:

```
self.centralwidget.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.context_menu_method)
```

so for that example you would need to adjust self.context_menu_method, that is what is actually creating the menu

and for a code example of how to add a submenu:

```
menu = QtGui.QMenu()
submenu = QtGui.QMenu(menu)
submenu.setTitle("Submenu")
menu.addMenu(submenu)
```

Comment: This has good information, but, its assuming that the OP has some code that is already connected to a custom context menu handler. I really get the sense that it might be possible he is trying to get a reference to a default context menu and then append to it before showing. That would make its answer somewhat widget dependent.

Comment: Yes; Picard supports plugins, and it is possible to add context menu entries to the default "Plugins" submenu.  I do this already, see https://github.com/brianfreud/Picard-plugins/blob/master/SearchEbay.py#L162 for an example.  Problem is, when there's multiple plugins, esp ones that add lots of menu entries like the ebay one (47 entries just by itself), the menu gets really cluttered and messy.  It'd be far better if I could figure how to add a "search" submenu inside the provided Plugins submenu, then ebay as a submenu of Search.  I think adding that structure would be a vast improvement.